# Haskell Int and Maybe Int

Tags: haskell, int, option-type

Essentially I have a function that uses Maybe Int's to display a Sudoku problem. The Solution to the Sudoku contains only Ints and the code for displaying the Grid will be almost identical, with the exception of Maybe Int used for Problems and Int used for Solutions.

Is it possible to use Int values for a function that requires Maybe Int, if so how?

Edit: Just would work, is there a way to convert a list of Int's into maybe Int's?

Comment: Wrap your Int value into `Just`?

Comment: Have edited my question a little as I did look into using Just.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `xs` is a `[Int]` and you want a `[Maybe Int]` instead, use `map Just xs`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Says I can accept the answer in 9 mins :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use "Just".

```
foobar :: Maybe Int -> IO ()
foobar x = print x

main = foobar (Just 3)
```

To convert a list, you could just use map.

```
maybeList :: [a] -> [Maybe a]
maybeList = map Just
```

If you do `Just` on the list itself, you'll end up with `Maybe [Int]`.

Comment: Thank you too, that's a nice way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

The `sequence` function in Prelude does just the opposite from what you need, but the `sequence` version in `Traversable` works for you:

```
import Data.Traversable as T

T.sequence $ Just [1..10]
--[Just 1,Just 2,Just 3,Just 4,Just 5,Just 6,Just 7,Just 8,Just 9,Just 10]
```

Of course `map Just` is easier in your case, but my version is handy if you have a list inside `Just`.